# Issue with useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I understand that my code is wrong in terms of its use of useState and useEffect, but I dont really understand what I could do to fix it. The end goal is that every time I press loginButton, its supposed to use firebase authentication and use the setUser function to store the value of result.user into user. How would I go along fixing this.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faGoogle} from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import { auth, provider, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider, onAuthStateChanged } from '../firebase'
import {useAuthState} from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth'

const Login = () => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({})
  var tempUser = {}
  const [isLogged] = useAuthState(auth)
  const googleSignIn = async() =>{
    const result  = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    tempUser = result.user
  }

  return (
        <div class="loginWrapper">
        <h1 className='title'>Monkey With The <br/> IMS.</h1>
        <button class="loginButton" onClick={()=>googleSignIn()} >Sign in With  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGoogle} /> </button>
        <p>Made with <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} style={{color: 'black'}} />, by Het Patel</p>
        </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: what will **result.user** give you ?

Comment: The user information that you get as a response from firebase authentication

Comment: Look, You can use that information in **setUser**. But the problem with the set user is that you can't use that information somewhere else. Do you use Redux or Context?

Comment: Im going to implement context as soon as I figure this out, because I need the user variable globally

Comment: That's the main reason you use context or redux. the only thing I can suggest right now is to save your data in local storage. And if you gonna learn one of those two I suggest you to learn redux instead of context.

Comment: You’re not calling setUser anywhere

Comment: @FarbodShabani This is a bad suggestion. Context is a React fundemental.

Comment: Dear @SlavaKnyazev, I worked with both of them, You understand that **Redux** is much cleaner and better option. I get that it's one of the react fundemental but learning that consept is different matter. If someone comes to and ask me which one should I study if I want to put time on one these two option I would gladly say Redux.
But if that person have the time to study both of them I would actually recommend them to study both of them so they know how helpful is redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need the extra state variable (`user/setUser`). The `useAuthState` hook, already hands you a state variable *(named `isLogged` in your case, but I renamed it properly to `user` in my example)* that triggers a re-render, whenever the auth state changes and retains that auth state upon reloading the page.

Here's a simple setup **(Firebase v9)** to get you started:

```
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<...>",
  projectId: "<...>",
  storageBucket: "<...>",
  messagingSenderId: "<...>",
  appId: "<...>"
};
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

function Child({ user }){
  return <p>{ user ? user.displayName + " Logged In" : "Logged Out" }</p>
}

export default function App(){

  const [user] = useAuthState(auth); // <= Everything you need is here. This acts as a state variable (triggers a render whenever the 'user' gets updated) therefore you don't need an extra 'user/setUser' state
  const googleSignIn = async() =>{
    await signInWithPopup(auth, provider); // When the process successfully signs the user in, the 'user' variable above will be updated automatically.
  }
  return (
        <>
          <h1>Monkey With The IMS.</h1>
          {/* You can use the 'user' variable to conditionally render content based on the auth state */}
          { user ? 
            <button onClick={()=>signOut(auth)}>Logout</button>
            :
            <button onClick={googleSignIn}>Sign in With Google</button>
          }
          {/* ...or you can pass the user object down the hierarchy tree or use the Context API for a more robust sharing strategy */}
          <Child user={user} />
        </>
  )
};
```

Depending on your setup and use case, you might want to consider sharing the auth state using the Context API or through a state management library like Redux, Zustand and the like.

*References:*

[react-firebase-hooks/auth](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/auth#full-example)